# Calculate percentage in mySQL where SUM is already present in the table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have a table(Which I have no control over) like this:

[image]

As, you can see this already has total calculate in a separate row
I have to do calculate percentage which should look something like this:

[image]

The issue is how do I pass Total in a sub query like
`SELECT Marks from <TABLE> WHERE Topic = 'Total'`;

, so that I only get a single row?

Thanks

Comment: You might be better off joining the non-Total records to the Total records on Name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something along the lines of

```
SELECT m1.*, ROUND(m1.marks / m2.marks * 100, 2) percentage
  FROM marks m1 join marks m2
    ON m1.name = m2.name AND m2.topic = 'Total'
 ORDER BY name, topic
```

Output:

```
| Name |   Topic | Marks | percentage |
|------|---------|-------|------------|
|  Joe |    Chem |    43 |      26.38 |
|  Joe |   Maths |    75 |      46.01 |
|  Joe | Physics |    45 |      27.61 |
|  Joe |   Total |   163 |        100 |
...
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d602a/2)

Comment: This was helpful!

Answer (score 2):

The total **SHOULD NOT** be in the table. Given that you cannot modify it, I would just ignore that value and calculate the total and then calculate the percentage.

```
SELECT
    m.Name,
    Topic,
    Marks,
    Marks / t.Total * 100 AS Percentage
FROM
    marks AS m
JOIN (    
    SELECT
        Name,
        SUM(Marks) AS Total
    FROM
        marks
    WHERE 
        Topic != 'Total'
    GROUP BY
        Name) AS t ON t.Name = m.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

In a subquery select the row with the same name and the topic `'Total'`.

```
SELECT t1.name,
       t1.topic,
       t1.marks,
       t1.marks
       / (SELECT t2.marks
                 FROM elbat t2
                 WHERE t2.name = t1.name
                       AND t2.topic = 'Total')
       * 100 percentage
       FROM elbat t1;
```

Another option is using a join.

```
SELECT t1.name,
       t1.topic,
       t1.marks,
       t1.marks
       / t2.marks
       * 100 percentage
       FROM elbat t1
            LEFT JOIN elbat t2
                      ON t2.name = t1.name
                         AND t2.topic = 'Total';
```

`name` is required to be unique and there must only be one row with `'Total'` per name. Otherwise the subquery will throw an error about returning more than one row. With the join there's no such error but nonsense/ambiguous results.

You might also think about the case when there's a total of `0`, as this would trigger a division by zero error.

The table design alas is bad. Tables represent relations, not spreadsheets. The rows with the total have no business being in there. Lookup relational normalization.